# Applet not displaying correctly in browser

Tags: java, html

Applet loads in browser but leaves one of my inputs off and does not do any computing like it should

checked the java settings and also tried to manipulate the applet to allow the full HTML to display

```
Label lblsandwich = new Label("Number of Sandwiches: ");
Label lblfries = new Label("Number of Fries: ");
Label lbldrink = new Label("Number of Drinks: ");
Label lblsandwichcost = new Label("Total for Sandwiches: ");
Label lblfrycost = new Label("Total for Fries: ");
Label lbldrinkcost = new Label("Total for Drink(s): ");
Label lbltax = new Label("Tax Total: ");
Label lbltotal = new Label("Total Due: ");


TextField txtsandwich = new TextField(10);
TextField txtfries = new TextField(10);
TextField txtdrink = new TextField(10);
TextField txtsandwichcost = new TextField(10);
TextField txtfrycost = new TextField(10);
TextField txtdrinkcost = new TextField(10);
TextField txttax = new TextField(4);
TextField txttotal = new TextField(10);

Button btnCalculate = new Button("Calculate");

int intSandwich;
int intFries; 
int intDrink; 

final static double DOUBLE_TAX = 0.08;
final static double DOUBLE_SANDWICH = 2.50;
final static double DOUBLE_FRIES = 1.25;
final static double DOUBLE_DRINK = 1.00;

public void init()
{
    DesignLayout();
    txtsandwich.requestFocus();
    txtsandwich.addActionListener(this);
    txtfries.addActionListener(this);
    txtdrink.addActionListener(this);
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(this);


}

private void DesignLayout() {
    // Sets Layout Manager
    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    setLayout(gridbag);
    constraints.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

    // Row 1 Column 1 Label 
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblsandwich, constraints);
    add(lblsandwich);

    // Row 1 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtsandwich, constraints);
    add(txtsandwich);

    // Row 2 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblfries, constraints);
    add(lblfries);

    // Row 2 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtfries, constraints);
    add(txtfries);

    // Row 3 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lbldrink, constraints);
    add(lbldrink);

    // Row 3 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtdrink, constraints);
    add(txtdrink);

    // Row 4 Column 1 Button
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(btnCalculate, constraints);
    add(btnCalculate);


    // Row 4 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblsandwichcost, constraints);
    add(lblsandwichcost);

    // Row 4 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtsandwichcost, constraints);
    add(txtsandwichcost);

    // Row 5 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 5;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lblfrycost, constraints);
    add(lblfrycost);

    // Row 5 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtfrycost, constraints);
    add(txtfrycost);

    // Row 6 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 6;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lbldrinkcost, constraints);
    add(lbldrinkcost);

    // Row 6 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txtdrinkcost, constraints);
    add(txtdrinkcost);

    // Row 4 Column 1 Label 
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 7;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lbltax, constraints);
    add(lbltax);

    // Row 4 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txttax, constraints);
    add(txttax);


    // Row 6 Column 1 Label
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 8;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(lbltotal, constraints);
    add(lbltotal);

    // Row 6 Column 2 TextField
    constraints.gridx = 1; 
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gridbag.setConstraints(txttotal, constraints);
    add(txttotal);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Performs math and displays the totals


    double doubleSandwich;
    double doubleFries;
    double doubleDrink;
    double doubleTax;
    double doubleTotal;




    intSandwich = Integer.parseInt(txtsandwich.getText());
    intFries = Integer.parseInt(txtfries.getText());
    intDrink = Integer.parseInt(txtdrink.getText());
    doubleSandwich = intSandwich * DOUBLE_SANDWICH;
    doubleFries = intFries * DOUBLE_FRIES;
    doubleDrink = intDrink * DOUBLE_DRINK;

    txtsandwichcost.setText(String.valueOf("$" + doubleSandwich));
    txtfrycost.setText(String.valueOf("$" + doubleFries));
    txtdrinkcost.setText(String.valueOf("$" + doubleDrink));

    doubleTax = (doubleSandwich + doubleFries + doubleDrink) *     
    DOUBLE_TAX;
    txttax.setText(String.valueOf("$" + doubleTax));



    doubleTotal = doubleSandwich + doubleFries + doubleDrink + doubleTax;
    txttotal.setText(String.valueOf("$" + doubleTotal));



}
```

}

The actual results should have a label that says Number of sandwiches and a text box to input a number. everything else loads and displays but the first label and text box. Also the calculate button does nothing.

Comment: Applets aren't going to be displayed correctly in any browser, they're dead. Learn something else.

Comment: Applets do display correctly in browsers. I have several other applets that display with no problems at all. So I believe you are incorrect.

Comment: [Good luck](https://www.quora.com/How-am-I-am-supposed-to-run-a-Java-applet-if-browsers-do-not-support-it-anymore)!